# Checking row for duplicates in Sudoku

Tags: java, sudoku

When i tried to check the rows of the Sudoku for duplicate elements, nothing is returned as result. Don't know whether the code is right or not. If the duplicate element found in a row, then need to print repetition found. Help me to reach the solution with using the method `checkRow()`.

```
public class Sudoku {
 public static void main(String... args) throws Exception
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);        
    int[][] sudokuPuzzle = {    
                         {8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 9},       
                         {0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},                                                                                       
                         {3, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 1},
                         {0, 0, 9, 8, 0, 2, 7, 0, 0},
                         {0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0},
                         {0, 0, 4, 3, 0, 7, 1, 0, 0},
                         {1, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 2},
                         {0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0},
                         {2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 5}
                    };  
    printSudoku(sudokuPuzzle);
int count = countCellsToFill(sudokuPuzzle);
System.out.println("Number of cells have to filled: " + count);
}
 public static void printSudoku(int[][] sudokuPuzzle)
 {
  for (int i = 0; i < sudokuPuzzle.length; i++)
    {
        if (i == 3 || i == 6)
            System.out.println("------------------------");
        for (int j = 0; j < sudokuPuzzle[i].length; j++)
        {
            System.out.format("%-2s", sudokuPuzzle[i][j]);
            if (j == 2 || j == 5 )
                System.out.print(" | ");
        }           
        System.out.println();   
    }      
}

 public static int countCellsToFill(int[][] sudokuPuzzle){
int count=0;
for(int[] sudokuPuzzle1 : sudokuPuzzle){
    for(int a: sudokuPuzzle1){
        if(a == 0){
            count++;
        }
    }
}
return count;
}
 public boolean checkRow(int[] sudokuPuzzle){
for (int row = 0; row < sudokuPuzzle.length; row++)
{
        int num = sudokuPuzzle[row];
            if (num == sudokuPuzzle[row])
            {
                return true;
            }    
}
return false;
}     
}
```

Comment: please format and indent the code properly. Unindented code is near impossible to read,

Comment: And tell us what piece of code went wrong. What did you try and what where the results.

Comment: error is in _checkRow()_ method..there is no output is available for this.

Comment: `int num = sudokuPuzzle[row];if (num == sudokuPuzzle[row])` that will always be true

Comment: PS : you should not check `0` as this is your default/empty value, unless you want to return that as a duplicate too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a moment and read your code:

```
 public boolean checkRow(int[] sudokuPuzzle){
    for (int row = 0; row < sudokuPuzzle.length; row++)
    {
       int num = sudokuPuzzle[row];
       if (num == sudokuPuzzle[row])
       {
          return true;
       }    
    }
       return false;
 }
```

What you are doing here is picking up the first number, "8" in this case, because it is on your position "0". Then, you check if that "8" is on your position "0", which of course, will be always true.

If you wanna check numbers per row, I suggest you to analize it with, maybe, a double for. So you can do your 9 lines, 9 numbers per line, and gotta have in mind don't compare the number you just read with himself.

By the way, if you are doing a Sudoku, you should check if that number appears in the first square as well. Sodukus are composed by 9 squares, you can not repeat numbers in rows, nor in columns, nor in squares.

That is an easy problem, struggle a bit!

Comment: in your answer, it is one dimensional array... but my problem is two dimensional..

Comment: Well that's why you need a double for, as I said before.

Comment: i am a beginner.. can you please help me with double?

Answer (score 0):

Modified your checkRow method to check for duplicates -

```
public boolean checkRow(int[] sudokuPuzzle) {
    for (int row = 0; row < sudokuPuzzle.length; row++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sudokuPuzzle.length; i++) {
            if (i == row) {
                continue;
            }
            if (sudokuPuzzle[i] == sudokuPuzzle[row]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Actually your checkRow method signature accepts a one dimensional array, thus retained the same signature.